# Converting Atn function of VB Script for Python parser of ArcGIS Field Calculator?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, vbscript, python-parser

I would like to convert the Atn function (which [`returns the arctangent of a number`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx6we9k6(v=vs.84).aspx)) of VB Script to Python but I cannot find exactly the same function. Any help?

I want to convert the slope of percent to slope of degree but I cannot use the Slope tool of ArcGIS (slope to degree) as the slope has been already calculated in another tool.

So I have found this conversion (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.atan.aspx) and convert it to VB Script (in field calculator) using the following code:

```
Atn ( [Avg_Slope]/100  )*(180/3.14159265358979)
```

Comment: numpy (bundled with ArcGIS's python) already has an arctan function

Comment: Python Math module has atan, atan2

Comment: As said by @klewis, math module comes with Field Calculator as imported and simply math.atan(<expr>) will give you the result.

Comment: As I has read yeah the method math.atan seams to be the correct function, so I convert to the following Python script   math.atan(( !Avg_Slope! /100  )*(180/math.pi)).

The results I get are different from the expected one.

As I have search here is an online calculator and we can see the formula  http://www.calcunation.com/calculator/slope-percent-conversion.php

if I am trying to calculate insent of Avg_Slope--> 43...my script returns me the "0.241561"degress  but the online calculator says that i should have as a result "23.27" degrees.

Comment: Moreover if I  trying to use the formula of this online calculator http://www.calcunation.com/calculator/slope-percent-conversion.php  in python I write in field calculator math.atan( !Avg_Slope! /100 ).

Again it returns wrong results

Comment: Now, before anyone provides an answer to your original question, is an ideal time to revise it with where you are currently stuck.

Comment: math.atan(<expr>) does not return right results, comparing to the results of the following calculator ( http://www.calcunation.com/calculator/slope-percent-conversion.php )